# Outlook 2007/2010 context menu item picture

Tags: c#, contextmenu, outlook-addin

I have a problem setting an image to the custom context menu item in the outlook. I have a strong requirement to use a custom image, that i was provided. 
 That's how i'm doing it right now:

```
Application.ItemContextMenuDisplay += ApplicationItemContextMenuDisplay;
```

...

```
 private void ApplicationItemContextMenuDisplay(CommandBar commandBar, Selection selection)
    {
        var contextButton = commandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, missing, true) as CommandBarButton;
        contextButton.Picture = ImageConverter.ImageToPictureDisp(Resources.ContextMenuIcon);
        contextButton.Visible = true;
        contextButton.Caption = Resources.ArchiveMail;
        contextButton.Click += ArchiveButtonClicked;
    }
```

My image converter looks like this:

```
public class ImageConverter : AxHost
{
    public ImageConverter() : base("59EE46BA-677D-4d20-BF10-8D8067CB8B33")
    {
    }

    public static IPictureDisp ImageToPictureDisp(Image image)
    {
        return (IPictureDisp) GetIPictureDispFromPicture(image);
    }
}
```

The image i'm using is bmp (16*16, 8 bit).
the problem is that there's no image in the outlook context menu for my new item. The button appears, it does what i want it to do, but no image is shown. And no exception is thrown. What can that be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try set `contextButton.Style=MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIconAndCaption`